# Is there a comparison table for quantum algorithms like VQE, QPE, QAOA, and so on?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-computer, algorithms

I have one question: Recently, I studied about several algorithms like VQE, QPE, QAOA and so on. I would like to make some comparison tables about those algorithms, their strengths and weaknesses. If you know some references (such as papers or books) about it, I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right stack Exchange website for this, probably Stack Overflow or Data Science SE would better

Comment: This may be helpful: https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/. But as others mentioned, try to ask on Quantum Computing SE.